# How can I get RuleContex in drools?

Tags: drools

I get KieSession, and I want to use property cancelMatch definition by interface RuleContext.
How can I get ruleContext instance with kieSession?
Thanks for help!

Comment: ... this is a strange question. What are you actually trying to do? A session is just the potential to run rules; you only have matches when you actually do run them.

Comment: Thanks for asking! I find the macro variable 'drools' instance of RuleContex, so I can get it from session!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that. What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?